# I want to convert a signature Image(array of png bytes) to signature Controller points

Tags: android, flutter, signature

I am using the signature library of flutter(https://pub.dev/packages/signature) to create a signature pad for the user:

```
signatureController = SignatureController(
  penStrokeWidth: 5,
  penColor: Colors.white,
  onDrawStart: startedDrawing,
);
```

I can export the signature controller to png array with:

```
final exportSignatureController = SignatureController(
  penStrokeWidth: 2,
  exportBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
  penColor: Colors.white,
  points: signatureController.points,
);

final signature = exportSignatureController.toPngBytes(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.round(), width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.round());
```

After that the signature image is stored and appears on user's screen:

```
Image.memory(
   Uint8List.fromList(signature.pngBytes),
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
   fit: BoxFit.contain,
),
```

I want to create a GestureDetector so the user can tap on the image and edit the signature. So, how can I convert the png bytes to signatureController points in order for the signature to appear to the signature pad?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
img.Image image = 
img.decodeImage(widget.previousSignature.pngBytes.toList());
List<Point> whitePixels = [];
for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
      int pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
      int red   = img.getRed(pixel);
      int green = img.getGreen(pixel);
      int blue  = img.getBlue(pixel);
      int alpha = img.getAlpha(pixel);

      if (red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255 && alpha == 255) {
        var offset = Offset(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble());
        whitePixels.add(Point(offset, PointType.tap, 1.0));
      }
    }
  }
```

and then you just set the whitePixels as the points of the Signature Controller